# media query en php

Tags: php, wordpress

no conozco mucho PHP y necesito mostrar una imagen segun el dispositivo en el header de mi post, por ahora los puedo imprimir por separado a traves de las variables $picure(para mobile) y $url(para desktop)

por ejemplo estas serian las media queries

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
 echo $picture;
}
@media (min-width: 601px) {
 echo $url;
}
```

codigo php
como se ve, las fotos se deberían imprimir en el header de la pagina segun las medias queries a traves de la propiedad background-image:url

```
  <?php $image = get_field('imagen-mobile-first');
 $picture = $image['sizes']['large'];?>
 <?php if($image): ?>
 <img src="<?php //echo($picture); ?>" class="img-fluid">
 <?php endif;?>
  <article <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
 <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' ); ?>


 <header class="entry-header post-image-noticias" style="background-image:url(<?php 
 echo $url ?>);">
```

Comment: Que es lo de arriba? una combinacion con css y php??

Comment: es para que se entienda la idea ?! pero eso necesito hacerlo en PHP

Comment: pues no conosco si existe una forma de obtener el tamaño de una pantalla mediante php, por javascript si existe, puedes guiarte por alli

Comment: Como se te ocurre? crear las media queries con js? se me ocurre algo como cambiar las variables php por las variables js

Comment: En javascript existen una funcion para obtener los tamaños actuales de una pantalla, puedes utilizar eso con unas condicioanles y dependiendo de las resoluciones hacer un cambio en el src, podrias hacer todo eso dentro de php con javascript, no me me ocurre un buen metodo pero esa es una solucion, porque con php no sera facil